# JasperPrint Ireport

Tags: java, jasper-reports

Porque a instrução seguinte é executado no Windows e não linux?

```
JasperPrintManager.printReport(relatorio, true);
```

Na janela abrir o diálogo da impressora, mas em Linux mostrar o próximo erro:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Reportar erro de impressão.

Metodo:

```
public void imprimir() {
        try {
            //Navegar na arvore da aplicacao
            DataTable tabela = (DataTable) Faces.getViewRoot().findComponent("formListagem:tabela");
            Map<String, Object> filtros = tabela.getFilters();

            String razaoInstituicao = (String) filtros.get("razaosocial");
            String cnpjInstituicao = (String) filtros.get("cnpj");

            String caminho = Faces.getRealPath("/reports/instituicao.jasper");

            Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();

            if(razaoInstituicao == null){
                parametros.put("razaosocial", "%%");
            }else{
                parametros.put("razaosocial", "%" + razaoInstituicao + "%");
            }
            if(cnpjInstituicao == null){
                parametros.put("cnpj", "%%");
            }else{
                parametros.put("cnpj", "%"+ cnpjInstituicao + "%");
            }

            Connection conexao = HibernateUtil.getConexao();

            JasperPrint relatorio = JasperFillManager.fillReport(caminho, parametros, conexao);
            JasperPrintManager.printReport(relatorio, true);

            Messages.addGlobalInfo("Relatório Gerado com sucesso!");

        } catch (JRException erro) {
            Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar imprimir a instituição!");           
            erro.printStackTrace();
            Messages.addGlobalError(erro.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Console:

> net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error printing report.
>         at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT.printPages(JRPrinterAWT.java:214)
>         at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.print(JasperPrintManager.java:242)
>         at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.print(JasperPrintManager.java:129)
>         at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrintManager.printReport(JasperPrintManager.java:326)
>         at br.pro.sispro.migreja.bean.InstituicaoBean.imprimir(InstituicaoBean.java:210)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>         at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:247)
>         at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:267)
>         at javax.faces.event.MethodExpressionActionListener.processAction(MethodExpressionActionListener.java:149)
>         at javax.faces.event.ActionEvent.processListener(ActionEvent.java:88)
>         at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.broadcast(UIComponentBase.java:814)
>         at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:300)
>         at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
>         at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
>         at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
>         at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
>         at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>         at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
>         at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:658)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>         at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:78)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:108)
>         at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:522)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
>         at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
>         at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
>         at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
>         at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.service(AjpProcessor.java:780)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
>         at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:785)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1425)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>         at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException
>         at sun.print.PSPrinterJob.printDialog(PSPrinterJob.java:433)
>         at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.print.JRPrinterAWT.printPages(JRPrinterAWT.java:198)
>         ... 46 more

Comment: O erro não esclarece muita coisa. Você já tentou mudar o path?